# Ajax disable star rate after vote

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, rate

i have problem with my rate, my code like below

```
$(function(){
    var href = jQuery(location).attr('href');

    $('.rate-it').rating({
        required: true,
        callback: function(value, link){ 
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<? echo base_url('post/rate/'); ?>",
                dataType: "json",
                data: "&postlink=" + href + "&ratevalue=" + value,
                success: function(msg){
                    $('.rate-it').attr('disabled', true);
                },
                error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    displayError();
                }
            });
        },
```

how to set people to can not vote repeatedly?
i'm using codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    var href = jQuery(location).attr('href');

    $('.rate-it').rating({
        required: true,
        callback: function(value, link){ 
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<? echo base_url('post/rate/'); ?>",
                dataType: "json",
                data: "&postlink=" + href + "&ratevalue=" + value,
                success: function(msg){
                    $('.rate-it').attr('disabled', true);
                },
                error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    displayError();
                }
            });
        },

        focus: function(value, link){
            var tip = $('#rate-result');
            tip[0].data = tip[0].data || tip.html();
            tip.html(link.title || 'value: '+value);
        },

        blur: function(value, link){
            var tip = $('#rate-result');
            $('#rate-result').html(tip[0].data || '');
        }           
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want someone not to be able to vote repeatedly, you have to disable the button AND check on the server side that this client didn't vote yet.

Otherwise one could intercept the ajax request and repeat it.

You can try it :

In firefox or chrome, browse to your site, type F12, go to the console menu and copy the following :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "[your url here]",
    dataType: "json",
    data: "&postlink=" + href + "&ratevalue=" + value,
});
```

Launching it with ctrl + enter, you send a vote request.
Now put that in a for loop, and you have tons of votes.

Globally, keep in mind that you never clean user input on the client side.